# Where is an error in WSDL file?

Tags: php, wsdl

I want add in wsdl file function which gets 2 parameters...i've made complextype, but still no good result...could anyone explain, what i'm doing wrong?

here are

```
wsdl pastebin.com/JWnFUF1b

server: pastebin.com/aSbdRdRf

client: pastebin.com/4SLL0wWm
```

Thx in advance!

/**** EDITED ****/

function in server:

here is i'm trying simply test variables which must get function...first is working, second - no...that's why main code above is commented out

```
function votedBierOrNo($name,$user)
    {
        /*$voted = new VotedBierOrNo();
        $data = $voted->votedOrNo($name,$user);
        return json_encode($data);*/
        return $user;
    }
```

client:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/bierdb_service/bier.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'trace'=>true));

echo ($client->__call("votedBierOrNo", array(
                                                "bier_name" => "Infinium",
                                                "user_id"   => "12345"
                                            )
                        )
    );
```

Comment: What is the error? Where does it go wrong? How do you call it?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5 you can use SoapClient on the WSDL to call the web service functions. For example:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
```

and $client is now an object which has class methods as defined in some.wsdl. So if there was a method called `getTime` in the WSDL then you would just call:

```
$result = $client->getTime();
```

And the result of that would (obviously) be in the $result variable. You can use the `__getFunctions` method to return a list of all the available methods.

**Is the method you want to call available in the result of getFunctions?**

Also, take a look at this snippet. This is example code of someone who consumed a complextype soap service : http://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/consuming-soap-complextype-webservice-with-php/

You can also consider putting a try/catch block around it, maybe the error will point you in the right direction:

```
 try {
   // Your soap call
 } catch(Exception $fault) {
    var_dump($fault);
 }
```

Comment: yes..this method is present in output from getFunctions.

Comment: i'm getting back just NULL

Comment: when i'm trying return first argument from server function, i have a result..but not with second..with secdond just "null"